# Given a jQuery, how to get the first result element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a variable and a jQuery in it, how can I execute the query and get the first resulted DOM element itself (if any)?

```
var $myQuery = $(...)
var domNode = $.myQuery<what to write here?> // and what if the query has not results?
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to ask, but using $() invokes the jquery function. Do you want to save the selector for future use?

Comment: I want to save the _result_ for later use (only the first one)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns the native DOM object

```
var domNode = $myQuery[0] //undefined if there is not any element.
```

or

```
var domNode = $myQuery.get(0) // Identical to above, only slower (according to doc).
```

## Resource

- [How do I pull a native DOM element from a jQuery object?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)

Comment: I searched for "how to execute" or "how to get", but never thought "pull" :-). Anyway thx.

Answer (score 1):

To get the first result, you can use this:

```
var domNode = $.myQuery[0]
```

If the result is blank, it will return `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like

```
var $myQuery = $('.selector-class');
var domNode = $myQuery.eq(0);
```